# IF Statement with multiple conditions always saying true (nested in while loop)

Tags: r

Please see my code below.

I have a data frame where each race a person identifies with is in a column (ex. AWHITE, ABLACK, etc.) and if they identify with this race then the entry is 1 (if not the entry is 2). Respondents can identify with more than one race.

I'm trying to identify when a respondent has stated they belong to more than one race. If they do, I want one column (ARACE) to update to 91 and another column (AOTHRACE) to become 2.

The if statement (in the code below) is always evaluating to TRUE. Even though this is not correct. There are respondents who identify as only one race (i.e. white). I've looked this over multiple times, but I can't find where I've messed up.

I plan to use more if statements (if, else if) for the other races/columns as well (i.e. a respondent identifies as black AND at least one other race), but I can't even get the first one to work, so I haven't implemented that.

(I don't actually want the else to be 0, I just used that to confirm the code wasn't working as expected. When I ran the summary function on ARACE the minimum was 91, so I know this statement was never evaluated.)

```
i <- 0
while (i <= nrow(nhes05v2)){
  if ((nhes05v2$AWHITE == 1) && (any(nhes05v2$ABLACK==1, nhes05v2$AAMIND==1, nhes05v2$AASIAN==1, nhes05v2$APACI==1))){
    nhes05v2$ARACE = 91
    nhes05v2$AOTHRACE = 2}
  else {nhes05v2$ARACE = 0
  nhes05v2$AOTHRACE = 0}
  i <- i+1}
```

Here's an example of the values:

```
> nhes05v2$AWHITE[1:20]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
> nhes05v2$ABLACK[1:20]
 [1] 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
> nhes05v2$AASIAN[1:20]
 [1] 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
> nhes05v2$AAMIND[1:20]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
> nhes05v2$APACI[1:20]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I would like the output to be something like *(this would be with more than just my one if statement above, there'd be more `if, else if`, but since I'm stuck on the first I haven't gone past that)*

```
> nhes05v2$ARACE[1:20]
 [1] 0 91 0 91 0 91 91 0 0 91 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> nhes05v2$AOTHRACE[1:20]
 [1] 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Currently the output is

```
> nhes05v2$ARACE[1:20]
 [1] 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91
> nhes05v2$AOTHRACE[1:20]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Are your race variables (`AWHITE`, `ABLACK`, `AAMIND` , etc.) coded as numeric or factor levels?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible and testable. Please share a reproducible example of your data frame and the expected output. It is likely that we don't need any for-loop or while-loop to achieve your task.

Comment: @NM_ they are currently numeric

Comment: @www I've edited to add some context. 

Thank you both for your feedback!

Comment: In order to belong to more than one race, is it possible for some one to be of two non-white races (for example, Asian and Black)? This is because your current if statement considers that a person is more than one race if they are white + at least one more race (i.e. in order to be mixed, that have to be white + some other race).

Comment: @NM_ Thank you for clarifying. Yes they can. I've updated the desired input and output above. In the 7th column the person does not identify as white, but as two other races.

Comment: @jazlaw were you able to get the result you wanted with the code I provided as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by recoding the 2 to 0 (i.e, 0 = "No") and using the following code with 2 functions used to determine whether a record satisfies criteria.

Please note that the code assumes that the race variables are numeric.

```
# Replicate your example
AWHITE = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1", " ")))
ABLACK = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2", " ")))
AASIAN = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2", " ")))
AAMIND = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2", " ")))
APACI = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2", " ")))

nhes05v2 = data.frame(AWHITE, ABLACK, AASIAN, AAMIND, APACI)
> nhes05v2  # Partial output given
   AWHITE ABLACK AASIAN AAMIND APACI
1       1      2      2      2     2
2       1      1      2      2     2
3       1      2      2      2     2
...
18      1      2      2      2     2
19      1      2      2      2     2
20      1      2      2      2     2
```

Recode the variables

```
# Recode variables. Change all 2's to 0's (New coding is 1 = Yes, 0 = No).
nhes05v2[nhes05v2 == 2] = 0
```

Create 2 functions to satisfy criteria for `ARACE` and `AORACE`

```
# A person is mixed race it they answer 1 to more than one race
# Therefore a person whose row sum is greater than 1 is mixed race

determine.arace = function(AWHITE, ABLACK, AAMIND, AASIAN, APACI){
  ifelse( sum(AWHITE, ABLACK, AAMIND, AASIAN, APACI ) > 1 , 91, 0)
}

determine.aothrace = function(AWHITE, ABLACK, AAMIND, AASIAN, APACI){
  ifelse( sum(AWHITE, ABLACK, AAMIND, AASIAN, APACI ) > 1 , 2, 0)
}
```

Apply these functions to your data

```
ARACE = mapply(determine.arace, nhes05v2$AWHITE, nhes05v2$ABLACK, nhes05v2$AAMIND, nhes05v2$AASIAN, nhes05v2$APACI)
> ARACE
[1]  0 91  0 91  0 91 91  0  0  0  0  0  0 91  0  0  0  0  0  0

AOTHRACE = mapply(determine.aothrace, nhes05v2$AWHITE, nhes05v2$ABLACK, nhes05v2$AAMIND, nhes05v2$AASIAN, nhes05v2$APACI)
> AOTHRACE
[1] 0 2 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

To add them to your data frame

```
nhes05v2$ARACE = ARACE
nhes05v2$AOTHRACE = AOTHRACE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This easily gets me to what I need for all that extra code! And thank you for your comments to help clarify my question.

Comment: @jazlaw, glad to hear this! Good luck with your research :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` and `magrittr` packages, my best version of this looks like:

```r
nhes05v2 %>%
  mutate(ARACE = ifelse(AWHITE == 1 & (ABLACK == 1 | AAMIND ==1 | AASIAN == 1 | APACI == 1), 91, 0),
         AOTHRACE = ifelse(AWHITE == 1 & (ABLACK == 1 | AAMIND ==1 | AASIAN == 1 | APACI == 1), 2, 0))
```

The && conditional in R only checks against the first row, which is why you got the results you did here - [here's a post](https://github.com/hadley/strict/issues/32) from other people who have been flummoxed by that behavior.